# How to allow people to respond to a survey in SharePoint but not to add questions?

Tags: permissions, survey

I am trying to create a survey in SharePoint that I plan to share with some colleagues. The problem I am facing is that if I assign users with the "Visitor" (reader) profile, they are not given access to respond to the survey, while if they are assigned with the "Member" (contributor) profile, they can respond to the survey but can also get access to the survey setting and can therefore add their own questions (which I don't want them to do).

I am guessing there must be some specific permissions I need to assign or remove but I am not sure which.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks,

Nikos

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom Permissions level "Add items".

Then go to Survey settings and set permissions to users(permission level - "Add items").

[Here is compete guide - How to create permission level.](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-permission-levels/)

You need to check "Add items" and "View Items" in List Permissions section.